# Parse html tag from json response in kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2, html-parsing

Hey I am working in **json** response with **html** tag in kotlin. I don't understand how to parse html tag in response. I tried to work with [retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56557477/11560810) and [moshi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62242227/11560810). My response will look like this

**Response**

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "date": "2021-11-01",
      "title": "<html><head><style>body {
   color: black;
}
</style></head><body><h1 id="sample-markdown">Sample Markdown</h1>
<p>This is some basic, sample markdown.</p>
<h2 id="second-heading">Second Heading</h2>
<ul>
<li>Unordered lists, and:<ol>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ol>
</li>
<li>More</li>
</ul>
<blockquote>
<p>Blockquote</p>
</blockquote>
<p>And <strong>bold</strong>, <em>italics</em>, and even <em>italics and later <strong>bold</strong></em>. Even <del>strikethrough</del>. <a href="https://markdowntohtml.com">A link</a> to somewhere.</p>
<p>And code highlighting:</p>
<pre><code class="lang-js"><span class="hljs-keyword">var</span> foo = <span class="hljs-string">'bar'</span>;

<span class="hljs-function"><span class="hljs-keyword">function</span> <span class="hljs-title">baz</span><span class="hljs-params">(s)</span> </span>{
   <span class="hljs-keyword">return</span> foo + <span class="hljs-string">':'</span> + s;
}
</code></pre>
<p>Or inline code like <code>var foo = &#39;bar&#39;;</code>.</p>
<p>Or an image of bears</p>
<p><img src="http://placebear.com/200/200" alt="bears"></p>
<p>The end ...</p>
</body></html>"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to show `title` in textview.

[image]

Is it possible in android we can do?

Answer (score 0):

You can render those html codes into a text view, try to use this library to do that.
https://github.com/SysdataSpA/SDHtmlTextView

Edit:
You can also use WebView to render html.

Comment: can we do without library?

Comment: Yes you can, follow this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116191/11209575

Comment: this library is not working

Comment: Sorry for waiting, have you solved it? If you haven't, please provide information what makes it doesn't work.

Comment: When  i am trying add dependency it giving error

Comment: What did the console show?

Comment: I also had problems with that library so I have published an updated version written in Kotlin.
https://github.com/iAmMONK/Spansimple